# MVC 4. Signalr/Hub not loading in IIS 7 but working correctly in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am working on a Web Application on the Asp .Net 4.0 framework that uses SignalR, having installed it from the Nuget package. When I debug or run the application without debugging locally it works correctly. However, when it is deployed to the production server it is unable to find the signal/hubs

Following flags in the web.config could not help.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Cassini or IIS Express? Can you run it on localhost on your Win7 dev machine? See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx  What's the error message?

Comment: With IIS Express it's ok, problem on shared hosting with IIS 7.0.

Comment: [HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/signalr/hubs&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2()...

Comment: Get it working on Win7/LocalHost

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like needs the use of @Url.Content("~/Signalr/Hubs") ... Ref: [Signalr FAQ](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq)

Should have been a comment but don't have enough reps :-(.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was configuring SignalR in a new windows 7 Virtual machine and finally found that there was an error when i go to .NET Compilation feature in Inetmgr

There was an error while performing this operation.
Details: 
Filename: \?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\web.config
Line number: 137
Error: Unrecognized element 'folderLevelBuildProviders'

So, all i had to do was to run "aspnet_regiis -iru" and it fixed the problem with 404 Issue.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET4BreakingChangesAndStuffToBeAwareOf.aspx